# How to prevent a long inline-block element that is adjacent to a float from moving to a new line?

Tags: html, css

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Zvn4/2/

I have a list of comments that I want to show as "bubbles".

```
<div class="item">
    <img>
    <div class="bubble">Hi, how are you?</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img>
    <div class="bubble">Super good. <br/>Thank you<br/>And you?</div>
</div>
```

I want the img on the left side and I want the bubble on the right side. This is what I came up with.

```
.bubble {
    display:inline-block;
}
.item img {
    float:left;
}
```

But if a message is very long, the bubble goes on the next line. How can I make the message stay on the same line?

I cannot set a max-width on the bubble because I need it be fluid.

Comment: What browser are you developing for?

Comment: IE7 and more recent browsers

Comment: This is actually one of those situations where a `table` might not be a bad thing to use. One column for the image, and another for the message. Having `white-space:nowrap` would fix the new line issue, but it will cause the message to keep going as one line as well.

Comment: The table layout solution is indeed easy. http://jsfiddle.net/3Zvn4/20/ But tables as so 1995 ;). thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be what you want.

```
.item {
    margin : 5px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    clear:both;    
}
.bubble {
    padding: 8px;
    background: #DBE8F9;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 65px;
    display: table-cell;
}
.item img {
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
    height:42px;
    width:42px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color:gray;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly. Now the bubbles are wider then they need to be. http://jsfiddle.net/3Zvn4/7/

Answer (score 1):

Just add `white-space: nowrap;` and `margin-right : 47px;` to `.item`

(47px is 5px original margin + 42px width of the floated img)

and `white-space: normal;` to `.bubble`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/3Zvn4/8/

**Explanation:** The `white-space:nowrap;` on the container div `.item` prevents the inline elements (including inline-block) from wrapping to the next line.
`white-space` is inherited by the children of an element, so you have to put `white-space:normal;` on `.bubble` so that its text will have normal wrapping within its width.

Comment: That makes it overflow to the right. I need to see the bubble.

Comment: It is still overflowing a bit.

Comment: @Sylvain Sure, I added the explanation to the answer.